# using progress bar in background worker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have 2 forms and at the second form I have a progress bar.
When I click a button on the Main Form opens Form2 with progress bar:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    this.Visible = false;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    //Show Form2 with progress bar
    Show_pb();
}
Form2 f_pb = new Form2();

Show_pb()
{
    f_pb.ShowDialog();
    f_pb.Activate();
}

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //... hard work...
}
```

After that in `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` I fill data to some controls in Form1:

```
void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //...updating DataGridView and TreeView...
}
```

Unfortunatelly, when bw_RunWorkerCompleted works, **marquee** Progress Bar is freezing and it looks like that the app is hanging.

What can I do?

Comment: It's easier if you keep the form with the `BackgroundWorker` with _whatever it is that is showing progress_.  In this case `MainForm` with your progress bar.  Consider moving `ProgressBar` to `MainForm` and getting rid of `Form2`.  If you must keep `Form2` then **don't** use `ShowModal()` as that will block everything else in your app until the dialog is dismissed

Comment: Can you share more code for `Show_pb()` and `bw_RunWorkerCompleted()`?  Need to see how dialog is shown and how you update progress

Comment: Edited.And I don't update progress.

Comment: Thanks.  Oh I meant `ShowDialog()`.  Yes don't use that, you're blocking your UI. _"And I don't update progress"_ - how do you expect the progress bar to move then??

Comment: Ok. The style of progress bar is marquee, it is activated and just moving through the bar again and again.

Comment: Post your code.  Showing a modal dialog that contains a marquee should not freeze it.  Modal dialogs have a local message pump so your marquee should be updated.  Even a progress bar on the main form will continue to update whilst the modal window is show(if it created it at any rate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing the progress dialog with `ShowDialog` blocks the UI thread, so there is no way that progress will be updated. The code updating stuff on the UI after the background worker is done can't execute for the same reason.

The way to go is:

1. Implement the background worker's progress event and have the background worker report progress in this event (this will be called in the context of the UI thread, so you don't have to worry about cross-thread problems)
2. Make the progress "dialog" a normal window that is topmost and looks like a dialog (you may need to implement further stuff to make sure it can't be deactivated and disable the main window, because it will continue being responsive).
3. In the progress event handler, update the progress status in the secondary window.

---

You say now in the comments that your progress bar is actually a marquee, not showing any real progress. Doesn't really matter to the solution - just don't do the progress update stuff.

The thing is that `ShowDialog` blocks your UI thread until the dialog is closed, which you can not do from your code. Make it a non-modal dialog and you should be fine.